# jQuery method not working as expected - toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Does anyone know why the following jQuery code doesn't work as expected?

HTML:

```
<div id="languageContainer">
    <div class="headerButton"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headerButtonClicked
{
background-image:url('background.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
color:#000000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".headerButton").click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().toggleClass(".headerButtonClicked");
});
```

I observed the DOM using Firebug and the class is appended to the parent element, but the style doesn't change. When I added the styling code inline it worked, so I am sure that it is not the CSS that is the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of the dot (`.`) - `toggleClass()` accepts class name, not a selector.

Try:

```
$(".headerButton").click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("headerButtonClicked");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RB89c/1/)